# how to Use jQuery AJAX .done variables in next query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to know how to return the page var from the done method so that next time there is a click on ".morePlease" it sends the new page value (incremented by my backend php returned and returned).

```
(function($) {
    var page ='';

$(document).on( 'click', '.morePlease', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    getMorePosts(page);
})

function getMorePosts(page) { 
    $.ajax({
    url: '<?=$ajaxUrl?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
    action: 'ajax_pagination',
    query_vars:'<?=$query?>',
    page: page
    }
    }).done(function(response) {
        var obj=$.parseJSON(response);
        page = obj.page;
    }).fail(function() {
       alert( 'no result ' ); 
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You will have to make the obj and page variables global, instead of making them local and clear them when not required.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep it outside to make it global and accessable in all your function

```
  page = 1;
 // now this page will be initialized once on page reload and its value 
 // will exists and changing on entire page
 (function($) {
      $(document).on( 'click', '.morePlease', function( event ) {
         event.preventDefault();
         getMorePosts(page);
      })

     function getMorePosts(page) { 
         $.ajax({
             url: '<?=$ajaxUrl?>',
             type: 'post',
             data: {
                 action: 'ajax_pagination',
                 query_vars:'<?=$query?>',
                 page: page
             }
         }).done(function(response) {
             var obj=$.parseJSON(response);
             page = obj.page;
         }).fail(function() {
             alert( 'no result ' ); 
         });
   }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks Meenesh Jain for pointing me in the right direction didn't seem to work for me though found setting global with the window. method did.

```
(function($) {
    window.page = '';

    $(document).on( 'click', '.morePlease', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        getMorePosts(page);
    })

    function getMorePosts(page) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=$ajaxUrl?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_pagination',
                query_vars:'<?=$query?>',
                page: page
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            var obj=$.parseJSON(response);
            window.page = obj.page;
        }).fail(function() {
            alert( 'no result ' ); 
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```